# How to Convert a WriteableBitmap image to Byte array in WinRt App

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-runtime

I want to convert a `WriteableBitmap` image to a `Byte[]` array using C# code in Windows store metro style apps.

Answer (score 8):

`WriteableBitmap` exposes `PixelBuffer` property of type `IBuffer` - a Windows Runtime interface which can be converted to a byte array with .NET `Stream`s

```
    byte[] ConvertBitmapToByteArray(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (Stream stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'IBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'AsStream' and the best extension method overload 'WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsStream(IRandomAccessStream)' requires a receiver of type 'IRandomAccessStream'

Comment: @V.G. Since it's an extension method, you'll need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`

Comment: This is the only answer (after extensive searching) that works in Windows Universal projects. .Net classes and namespaces have shifted since WPF, to Win 8 metro store to Universal Windows...so this answer is gold!