# How to convert WritableBitmap to Base64 string

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, writablebitmap, winrt-xaml-toolkit

In my application I am using `WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render()` method present in WinRT XAML toolkit for rendering xaml element. After rendering the xaml control I need to send this to server in the form of Base64 string. How I can convert this WritableBitmap class in to Base64 string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert a WriteableBitmap image to Byte array in WinRt App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184254/how-to-convert-a-writeablebitmap-image-to-byte-array-in-winrt-app)

Comment: The given question is not marked as answered by the user, moreover I need to convert the WritableBitmap as Base64 string.

Comment: You can convert a byte array to a Base64 string -- there's not a direct path from WriteableBitmap to a Base64 string.

Comment: See this for `byte[]` to base64 encoded string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134696/231316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `WriteableBitmap` to a png or jpg (there's an extension for that in the toolkit that you can probably modify to get the compressed image as byte array) to reduce the data size and then use `Convert.ToBase64String()` as Chris suggested to convert the bytes to Base64 string.