# Converting a VideoFrame to a byte array

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have been trying to convert a captured [VideoFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.videoframe/) object to a byte array with little success. It is clear from the documentation that each frame can be saved to a [SoftwareBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.aspx) object, e.g.

```
SoftwareBitmap bitmap = frame.SoftwareBitmap;
```

I have been able to save this bitmap as an image but I would like to obtain it's data and store it in a byte array. Many SO questions already deal with this **but** the SoftwareBitmap belongs to the Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace (not the more typical Xaml.Controls.Image which the other SO posts address, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array)) so traditional methods like `image.Save()` are unavailable.

It seems that each SoftwareBitmap has a `CopyToBuffer()` method but the documentation on this is very terse with regards to how to actually use this. And I'm also not sure if that's the right way to go?

**Edit:**

Using Alan's recommendation below I've managed to get this working. I'm not sure if it's useful but here's the code I used if anyone else comes across this:

```
private void convertFrameToByteArray(SoftwareBitmap bitmap)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        WriteableBitmap newBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);
        bitmap.CopyToBuffer(newBitmap.PixelBuffer);
        using (Stream stream = newBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        // do what you want with the acquired bytes
        this.videoFramesAsBytes.Add(bytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `CopyToBuffer()` method, you can copy pixel data to the PixelBuffer of a WriteableBitmap.

Then I think you can refer to [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184254/how-to-convert-a-writeablebitmap-image-to-byte-array-in-winrt-app) to convert it to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to access an ***encoded*** `byte[]` array from the `SoftwareBitmap` (e.g. jpeg):

```
private async void PlayWithData(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap)
{
    var data = await EncodedBytes(softwareBitmap, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);

    // todo: save the bytes to a DB, etc
}

private async Task<byte[]> EncodedBytes(SoftwareBitmap soft, Guid encoderId)
{
    byte[] array = null;

    // First: Use an encoder to copy from SoftwareBitmap to an in-mem stream (FlushAsync)
    // Next:  Use ReadAsync on the in-mem stream to get byte[] array

    using (var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, ms);
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(soft);

        try
        {
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ){ return new byte[0]; }

        array = new byte[ms.Size];
        await ms.ReadAsync(array.AsBuffer(), (uint)ms.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    }
    return array;
}
```